# CS1026: ) expected I am trying to apply loop on my asp.net page but I get an error

Tags: asp.net

I am trying like this:

```
Line 42: <%=
Line 43:    
Line 44:    For t = 1 to 50
Line 45:     "<p>This text is repeated 50 times</p>"
Line 46:
```

Comment: please go through the link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To post code, we prefer it without line numbers, please use the code formatting tool provided, and you will probably need to post a larger block of code for someone to help you.

Comment: Also, we don't know what `CS1026` is even if you do, so please make that clear. If it is an online course, add the link to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%

    For t = 1 to 50
%>
      <p>This text is repeated 50 times</p>
<%
    Next
%>
```

You're "asdfasdf" is an expression, not a statement, and as such it does nothing. [Which is what CS1026 means.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tc5zwdf7.aspx)

Also, for loops in VB.Net need a "Next"